# Spring autowire generic type

Tags: java, spring, generics, inversion-of-control

Spring (from version 4) claims to support generic type injection and I'm trying to do something like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractControl<T extends IService> {

@Autowired
private T service;

protected T getService(){
    return service;
}

public void setService(T service) {
    this.service = service;
}
```

}

then an extension of this class:

```
public class FooControl extends AbstractControl<LoginService> {
}
```

but Spring is trying to inject `IService`. Is it possible to inject the inherited type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving the `@Autowired` into the subclass, like this:

```
  public abstract class AbstractControl<T extends IService> {

    private T service;

    protected T getService(){
        return service;
    }

    public void setService(T service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
  }
```

And the subclass:

```
public class FooControl extends AbstractControl<LoginService> {

   @Override
   @Autowired
   public void setService(LoginService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, the setter is needed? Is not any other way, for example, with constructor autowiring by type?

Comment: It should work creating an `@Autowired` annotated constructor with the `LoginService` as parameter